# Rails help - unknown attribute 'creator_id' for Event

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
      
  has_many :events, foreign_key: :creator_id, class_name: "Event"
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :creator_id
end
```

When I go to the events/new route I get this error: `unknown attribute 'creator_id' for Event.` I have done the database migration, I have added `before_action`'s.

```
  def new
    @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
  end
```

Any ideas?

Update:

```
 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20210610064055  Create events
   up     20210610070312  Devise create users
   up     20210612072338  Add body title to event
   up     20210612091329  Add foreign key
```

**Further updates as requested in the comment section. **

Migrations file:

```
class AddForeignKey < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :creator_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Database schema file:

```
 create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "date"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "creator_id"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

Do I need to add a foreign key to the events table as well? I can see I have not done that which I believe is wrong...

Comment: Looks like migrations haven't run / restart server / stop spring type of problem

Comment: Updated question to add migration status. restarted server too. What is stop spring?

Comment: @Christian There is probably something wrong with your migration for Event, please provide the source for it.

Comment: Can you post the code of the migration files here as well? Otherwise it would be hard to help. Also, check your db/schema.rb file, when implemented right you should find sth like 't.bigint "creator_id", null: false' in the create_table "events" block.

Comment: I have added the schema.rb file and the foreign key migration I ran. Do I need to add the foreign key to the events table too, I believe I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key should be added to the table you're making a reference from. In this case you're making a reference from events to users. So creator_id would have to be added to events. And it references a specific users.id value. So you need to remove they foreign key from `users` and add it to `events` instead.

```
class AddForeignKey < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_column :events, :creator_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Also, no need to specify the foreign key in the rails model specifically. The [rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) state:

> By convention, Rails guesses that the column used to hold the foreign
> key on this model is the name of the association with the suffix _id
> added. The :foreign_key option lets you set the name of the foreign
> key directly:

So

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User"
end
```

Would suffice

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. To clarify, the foreign key needs removing from the User model also?

Comment: Yes, you make an association from another table to the user table. So you say: event.creator_id = user.id. Since users table already has the id column, you don't need to add it.

Comment: Where do I declare that `event.creator_id = user.id` ?

Comment: When creating/updating an event you can set a user. For example: Event.create!(creator: current_user). Or if you want to add in the ID: Event.create!(creator_id: current_user.id) `current_user` is a method in Devise which allows access to the current user. You could use it in your `EventsController`

Comment: Thanks for your help. The `creator_id` foreign key column in events didn't seem to work but changing that to `user_id` did. Possibly something else I am doing incorrectly but I'm passed this error at least